# Use while loop to increment values in an array, untill all values are => 100

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, while-loop

So this is one of the exercises in the book [how to think like a cs, python3](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/howtothink/latest/howtothink.pdf), at page 138:
Use a mask to multiply all values below 100 in the following list by 2:

`a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])`

Repeat this until all values are above 100. (Not manually, but by looping)
Then, select all values between 150 < a < 200.

**So I tried to do this:**

```
while a.all() <= 100:
    a[a < 100] *= 2

print(a[150 < a < 200])
```

It doesn't exit the loop, even though It stops multiplying after it reaches [230 160 284 156 152].

Sorry if this is a question that has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere...

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention. `a.any() < 100` also produces the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while np.count_nonzero(a<=100) > 0: 
    a[a<100] *= 2

print(a[(150<a) & (a < 200)])
```

There are two mistakes in your program. First, according to `numpy` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html), `np.all()`:

> Test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to True.
>   So it seems useless here.

Second, there is no `a < x < b` way to check if x is on interval [a,b]. The `NumPy` way to do it is `(a<x) & (x>b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This works now... I never got to the last statement, so I haven't even noticed how this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`a.all() <= 100` doesn't do what you want. You may wanna change it to the following:

```
(a <= 100).all()
```

Besides, first of all, that's not a good idea to use that condition for your `while` loop. Secondly, your array is contain both items more and less than `100` which make your condition and hence the while loop useless. Also there's no point of using `numpy` if you want to do such thing using a simple loop instead of doing it in a vectorized way. You can simply use a python list.

Comment: Your solution is correct, I just don't understand almost everything in your explaining paragraph. 1. Why is this condition not a good idea? 2. `a` is altered within the loop, so it is not useless. 3. The way `a` is altered works with numpy indexing and uses a math function applied to the whole array (i.e. vectorized), which needs numpy and doesn't work with lists.

Comment: @SpghttCd Firstly, Alternating the object which your condition is depend on may cause a lot of leaks in your program specially if you're using that object elsewhere. Secondly, a chain is as strong as its weakest link. This means that when you combine numpy and python that's the python which defines the final performance so why bother and make a lot of confusion by using a third party library while you could simply do the same job using Python's built-in functions/objects/libraries/etc.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd, you are absolutely correct, however I just tried to follow the exercise instructions, which state that you have to use an array